# Incrementally cutting a video using python?

Tags: video, python

I have a large 20 minute video that I would like to cut 3 frames, every 2 seconds from the video and then compile that video in to some sort of readable video format afterwards.
I have an advanced understanding of Python but I do not understand how to use video with Python and use it in that sort of way.

Comment: Programming questions are off topic here. If you have code that you are having problems with then post it at [so].

Answer (score 1):

You could use [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) to accomplish this.

[This](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/videoclips.html) page explains how to create and export clips from an input video.

Comment: Ah right, where would I go to cut certain parts of the clip?

Comment: @Ethan It's all explained in the second page I linked. For example, you could export the video into a collection of frames, and then use ImageSequenceClip to convert the frames you want to keep back into a video. You might discard frames 118, 119, and 120 if the video is playing at 60 frames per second. Alternatively, you could use OpenCV to do something similar. A helpful article on how to do that for OpenCV in Python can be found here: https://medium.com/@iKhushPatel/convert-video-to-images-images-to-video-using-opencv-python-db27a128a481